# How to use properly Var() and cal() in Ionic 5 with Sass

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I am experiencing issues with using var and calc functions in combination with each other.
Here is my scenario

```
--variable-1 : 10px;
--variable-2 : 20px;
--variable-3 : calc(var(--variable-1) + var(--variable-2));
.some-class {
  width: var(--variable-3); // does not work
}
```

can someone explain why this is not working ?

Following some answers suggesting using $ to declare variables, I am more keen to understand how to -- variables work. and why is there 2 ways of defining variables.

what's the difference between $some-variable and --some-variable ?

Comment: your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/85fby1ju/

Comment: I found the problem. --variables or the so called CSS custom properties need to be used in the same scope. The reason my code wasn't working is that --variable-3 wasn't defined in the same scope as the other two. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to interpolate the variable while using it in calc function. You can do it something like this.

Here is the example i have modified your code you can take a look.

```css
$variable-1 : 12em;
$variable-2 : 4em;

.some-class {
  width: calc(#{$variable-1} + #{$variable-2});
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class"></div>
```

Comment: Ohh alright but take a look in my code I tried in a editor and its working sorry for editing the code lately

Comment: You code works! But I am asking why isn't it working with --variables. I know that it works with $ based variables

Comment: Your code will also work but instead of storing the calc function in another variable you declared it in the `width` property itself and will work!

Comment: Here is the link where you will understand the difference `https://blog.netcetera.com/the-difference-between-sass-less-variables-and-css-custom-properties-36d36f7584e3`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$a: 4em;
$b: 4em;

div {
  height: $a + $b;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: i also updated my code based on your new code... try this